# jQuery appended element using recursion is not displayed one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to append paragraph's to a container using recursive function.

The code looks like this -

```
loadSections (sections, buttons) {
        let sectionLength = sections.length;
        let self = this;
            this.sleep(sections[sectionCounter].DelayInMs);
            let context = {
              message: sections[sectionCounter].Text,
            };
            this.fillSections(context, function () {
                sectionCounter ++;
                if (sectionCounter < sectionLength) {
                    self.loadSections(sections, buttons);
                }
            });
    }

    fillSections (context, callback) {
        let messageList = $(document.createElement('p'));
        messageList.html(context.message);
        $('.chat-flow-container').append(messageList);
        callback();
    }

    sleep (milliSeconds) {
        let start = new Date().getTime();
        let expire = start + milliSeconds;
        while (new Date().getTime() < expire) { }
        return;
    }
```

The code just works. But the issue is all appended **p** elements into **.chat-flow-container** are not shown with the delay with I mentioned in sleep method, instead they all are shown together once the recursion ends.

Comment: setTimeout is not an option ?

Comment: @PRMoureu I do not want to use setTimeout

Comment: That `sleep` is bad design: it completely blocks the browser. Don't do that. You *should* consider `setTimeout`, and work with asynchronous code.

Comment: @trincot Sure. But why is the code behaving in that way ?

Comment: Because the sleep loop will block the browser, so it does not get the time to update the screen. Only when your JS runs to completion does the browser have a chance to process the pending work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The busy loop in the `sleep` method is preventing your browser from updating the screen. It blocks the browser. So this is not a good way to proceed.

Instead make your code asynchronous. If you have support for `async/await` then you could do it like this:

```
async loadSections(sections, buttons) {
    for (let section of sections) {
        await this.sleep(section.DelayInMs);
        let context = {
            message: section.Text,
        };
        this.fillSections(context);
    }
}

fillSections (context) {
    let messageList = $(document.createElement('p'));
    messageList.html(context.message);
    $('.chat-flow-container').append(messageList);
}

sleep (milliSeconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliSeconds));
}
```

Now `loadSections` will return immediately, but the code in it will still resume later when the `setTimeout` expires.

```js
const sections = [
  { DelayInMs:  300, Text: 'A' },
  { DelayInMs: 1000, Text: 'B' },
  { DelayInMs: 1000, Text: 'C' },
];
class X {
    async loadSections(sections, buttons) {
        for (let section of sections) {
            await this.sleep(section.DelayInMs);
            let context = {
                message: section.Text,
            };
            this.fillSections(context);
        }
    }

    fillSections (context) {
        let messageList = $(document.createElement('p'));
        messageList.html(context.message);
        $('.chat-flow-container').append(messageList);
    }

    sleep (milliSeconds) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliSeconds));
    }
}

new X().loadSections(sections);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat-flow-container"></div>
```